# Get an input from the user using graphics

Tags: java, input, 2d-games

I'm writting my first game and i want to add the name of the user to the high score chart. What is the best way to get the input from the user? except using JOption.

Needless to specify that i am drawing my game continuously. Maybe i can use JTextField?

Comment: If you don't want to mess up the layout of your game window, I would suggest either making a new JFrame with a JTextField that's created when the game is finished, or using a KeyListener to create your own TextField, which would be a pain but you could customize it to your liking.

Comment: I think that opening a new JFrame would be the best outcome for my game, how can i create my own textField using KeyListener?

Comment: The KeyListener can log the key strokes, and call a method that paints each key pressed to the screen as if the use if entering text into your window. Then you can detect the user hitting "enter" and save a list of the key strokes as the name. If you aren't familiar with key listeners, I can add some code to get you started.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are rendering your game onto a JComponent, yes you can just add a JTextField onto your renderer component.  Or you can render your own text field if you want to customize the look of everything.

To do a custom renderer:

Somewhere in your code, store the location of the text input box.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200,200,250,30);
String text = "";
```

In your rendering code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  // You can play with this code to center the text
  g.drawString(text, r.x, r.y+r.height);
}
```

Then you just need to add a keylistener somewhere in your constructor.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    text+=e.getKeyChar();

    //you might not need this is you are rendering constantly
    repaint();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do that please?

Comment: Example of the JTextField or the render?

Comment: I creatied a method called addKeyListener outside the constructor and she is empty. When i press a button it is not entering the keyPressed function.

Comment: You should be CALLING a method called addKeyListener, not writing it.